# After refresh of flask template matplotlib graphs error

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I have to display 2 matplotlib graphs in my flask template. I am getting desired output but, as I am new to matplotlib, I can't figure out why after refresh the first bar graph changes to the second plot. Here are three functions that are doing the job.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import base64
import StringIO

@app.route('/FirmIn/admin/')
def admin():
    plot_url=rendergraph1()
    plot_url2=rendergraph2()
    return render_template('admin.html', plot_url=plot_url, plot_url2=plot_url2)

def rendergraph1():
    cursor.execute("SELECT category,count(*) from project_info group by category")
    dataall=cursor.fetchall()
    img = StringIO.StringIO()
    category,index,count =[],[],[]
    i=0
    for data in dataall:
        category.append(data[0])
        index.append(i)
        count.append(data[1])
        i=i+1
    print index, count
    plt.bar(index, count, color = 'r')
    plt.xticks(index, category, rotation=25)
    plt.yticks(range(min(count), max(count)+1))
    plt.rcParams['xtick.major.pad']='5'
    plt.savefig(img, format='png')
    img.seek(0)
    plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
    return plot_url

def rendergraph2():
    cursor.execute("SELECT category,sum(project_cost) from project_info group by category")
    img = StringIO.StringIO()
    dataall=cursor.fetchall()
    category,index,cost =[],[],[]
    i=0
    for data in dataall:
        category.append(data[0])
        index.append(i)
        cost.append(data[1])
        i=i+1
    plt.plot(index,cost)
    plt.xticks(index, category, rotation=25)
    plt.savefig(img, format='png')
    img.seek(0)
    plot_url2 = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
    return plot_url2
```

And inside template I am displaying using:

```
<img style="height:400px" src="data:image/png;base64, {{ plot_url }}">
<img style="height:400px" src="data:image/png;base64, {{ plot_url2 }}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is because it is updating on the only available canvas or window. In order to display the two images separately, you need to create two separate windows so as to retain both of the plots.

To do this include the line

```
plt.figure()
```

..before

```
plt.plot()
```

In both `rendergraph1()` and `rendergraph()` methods.

This should take care of the issue. :)